# Retrieving a list of change events

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to work on a task which will find all recent changes to any fields for an `Opportunity` within the system.

It looks as if [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) takes care of this, but I'm struggling to implement it.

#### Done so far

- Added `Opportunity` to the `Change Data Capture` list in Setup
- Made a change to an Opportunity

#### Problem

Now, I'm trying to call the API and find the change that I've made.

According to [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_objects_change_data_capture.htm) (Subscription Channels section), it seems like all changes will be found at `/data/ChangeEvents`, but the URL is not qualified, and there are no examples, so I don't know exactly where I should be directing the request.

#### What I've tried

http://{myentity}.salesforce.com/data/ChangeEvents
http://{myentity}.salesforce.com/data/v47.0/ChangeEvents

Both gave `URL No Longer Exists`

http://{myentity}.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/ChangeEvents
http://{myentity}.salesforce.com/services/data/ChangeEvents

both gave

```
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
```

myentity.../services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel

```
        "urls": {
            "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel/{ID}",
            "defaultValues": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
            "describe": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel/describe",
            "sobject": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel"
        }
    },
    "recentItems": []
```

myentity.../services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember

```
        "urls": {
            "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember/{ID}",
            "defaultValues": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
            "describe": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember/describe",
            "sobject": "/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember"
        }
    },
    "recentItems": []
```

I have been able to successfully retrieve and update data through the API, so I'm certain that there aren't any problems with authorisation or any other config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the feature temporally backwards.

> Now, I'm trying to call the API and find the change that I've made.
>
> According to this page (Subscription Channels section), it seems like all changes will be found at /data/ChangeEvents, but the URL is not qualified, and there are no examples, so I don't know exactly where I should be directing the request.

Change Data Capture is intended for use with a subscription model. You, or your off-platform application, receive a stream of capture events that take place *while* you are subscribed and have an active connection to Change Data Capture. While you can use the replay capabilities of CDC to request the delivery of events that you missed while your subscription is offline, the intent is not that you should request change details on some cadence after the fact, and there's not an HTTP endpoint that you can hit to get a flat list of changes.

The [Change Data Capture Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_emp_connector.htm) has code samples for how to subscribe using EMP Connector.

Your use case seems closer to the [sObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) REST API endpoint.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Clearly I was misunderstanding its intended use.  "sObject Get Updated" does indeed look perfect for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement:

> I am trying to work on a task which will find all recent changes to any fields for an Opportunity within the system.

If having change data capture running almost continually to detect the changes is overkill for the requirement you could also consider the more basic [`getUpdated()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm) method that the SOAP API exposes.

You can make a single API call and find all the Opportunity records that were modified in a given time period.